# How to display disk space information on Windows 7 desktop

Tags: windows-7

I have a Windows 7 PC, and I'd like to display an icon/overlay on the desktop that shows how full the C drive on the machine is, in a similar way to how it is shown in Windows Explorer.

Is there a way to do this without using any external tools?

Comment: It used to be possible using desktop gadgets, but Microsoft stopped supporting this a long time ago, so the only way is to use software now. Software recommendations is considered off-topic though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such integrated functionality but there is plenty of utilities to do this. It would be best to search for something like "windows tray free disk" and check them for yourself.